# Google Chrome; refresh doesn't send If-Modified-Since header

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, http-headers, http-status-codes

As I am currently developing a website that simply must be able to perform more or less flawlessly under a lot of stress and switching from an automated test scenario, I would try the simple press-and-hold-F5-for-several-seconds-in-my-favorite-browser, and here I found an odd observation with Google Chrome:

If you do the above, Chrome skips sending the If-Modified-Since header, and the webserver is forced to fetch the page you want to display, resulting in a status code 200 instead of the expected 304.

In IE8 (and probably earlier versions also), this problem is **not** present.

Try this simple page: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, and then investigate the page closely with Fiddler; odd huh?

My question is; is this by design, or a bug from Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a by-design issue. Browsers will often send different requests when refreshing; for instance, try hitting CTRL+F5 in IE and you should see that IE then makes an unconditional HTTP request.

Are you sending proper HTTP-caching directives on your responses such that their freshness need not be verified?  http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf

Comment: So what you saying is, that Chrome by design has implemented a "CTRL+F5" pendant when pressing and holding F5? That actually make sense, but I am not a fan of this automated unconditional HTTP request. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing Shift-F5 or Ctrl-F5?  If so it would appear that [that is by design](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-discuss/browse_thread/thread/e69bbe6ba1b0a5fa?pli=1).  Otherwise it could very well be a bug.

Comment: I don't get your answer here; neither SHIFT+F5 nor CTRL+F5 makes any difference in Chrome, but thanks anyway :-)